# Sequence values/ Discrete Mathematics

Tags: sequences-and-series

$H_0=5, H_2=5$
Is $H$ nondecreasing? I really don’t understand how to prove/answer this mathematically if both values are the same?

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is decreasing if $\forall n \in N, H_n \ge H_{n+1}$.

A sequence is strictly decreasing if $\forall n \in N, H_n > H_{n+1}$.

A sequence is increasing if $\forall n \in N, H_n \le H_{n+1}$.

A sequence is strictly increasing if $\forall n \in N, H_n < H_{n+1}$.

Comment: So because 5 < 5+1 and 5< or equalto 5+1, its nondecreasing?